# Draw line to connect centroids

Tags: matlab, image-processing, line, centroid

I have an image

[image].

After I process to find centroid, it has four centroids.
My goal is I want to connect them using line and measure the angle between this area. To be clear about the centroid and my goal, you can open [image].

Here it is my code to achieve the centroid

```
I = imread('22c.jpg');
Ibw = im2bw(I);
Ibw = imfill(Ibw,'holes');

Ilabel = bwlabel(Ibw);
stat = regionprops(Ilabel,'centroid');
imshow(I); hold on;
for x = 1: numel(stat)
    plot(stat(x).Centroid(1),stat(x).Centroid(2),'ro');
end
```

The problem is I am still confused to do the next (to connect each centroids and measure the angle). I need your help, thanks

Comment: Your task is not clear. What do you mean by "measure the angle between this area"?

Comment: In picture you have circled inside the square too, but when i run your code, i don't get that circle. How did you get that?

Comment: What is the difference between this question and your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30462831/2545927)?

Comment: @OphirGvirtzer I mean calculate the angle inside circle area

Comment: @SanthanSalai It's just illustration

Comment: @kkuilla it is difference. This post is asking about calculate angle inside circled area, then the previous one is asking about calculate angle from intersection of lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [file exchange link](http://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28190-bresenham-optimized-for-matlab/content/bresenham.m) to `bresenham.m`

**Changed your code to get all the 4 centroids**

```
%// read your input image
im = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeqe8.jpg');

BW = im>220;

CC = bwconncomp(BW);
stat = regionprops(CC,'Centroid');

figure; imshow(BW); hold on
for x = 1: numel(stat)
    plot(stat(x).Centroid(1),stat(x).Centroid(2),'ro');
end
```

**Here is the output:**

[image]

## Further implementation:

```
%// putting all the Centroid coordinates into corresponding x,y variable
x = [stat(1).Centroid(1),stat(2).Centroid(1),stat(3).Centroid(1),stat(4).Centroid(1)];
y = [stat(1).Centroid(2),stat(2).Centroid(2),stat(3).Centroid(2),stat(4).Centroid(2)];

%// obtain row and col dim
[r,c] = size(BW);

%// get all x,y values connecting the centroid points
[xAll{1},yAll{1}] = bresenham(x(1),y(1),x(4),y(4));
[xAll{2},yAll{2}] = bresenham(x(2),y(2),x(3),y(3));
[xAll{3},yAll{3}] = bresenham(x(3),y(3),x(4),y(4));

%// change row and col subs to linear index
for ii = 1:3
    idx{ii} = sub2ind(size(BW),yAll{ii},xAll{ii});
end

%// change grayscale image to 3D (as you want red line)
out = repmat(im,[1,1,3]);

%// obtaining corresponding index of all 3 slices
for ii = 1:3
    idxall{ii} = bsxfun(@plus, idx{ii},[0:2].*(r*c));
end

%// keep only the index of 1st slice to 255 and changing rest to 0 to obtain a red line.
%// Similar process for blue line except keep the index in the 3rd slice to 255
out(cat(1,idxall{:})) = 0;
out(idx{1}) = 255;
out(idx{2}) = 255;
out(idx{3}+2*(r*c)) = 255;

%// see what you have obtained
figure; imshow(out);hold on
for x = 1: numel(stat)
    plot(stat(x).Centroid(1),stat(x).Centroid(2),'bo');
end
```

**Result:**

**Note:** The line may look dotted due to the picture's large size, but its continuous

[image]

Last figure zoomed to see continuous line:

[image]

## Going further:

You may have to take the advice of @Spektre to find the angle of inclination using `atan2`. Also refer [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30477232/2111163) for more explanation.

Comment: @ArseneWe I think ArseneWe got 4 points (2 centroids and 2 bone edge peaks) so he have 2 lines/axises instead of one. In this solution is needed the angle between the two line/axises. The problem is that the centroid is not precise and does not necessarily represent point on bone axis which renders it unusable for this task (unless the bones are symmetrical and horizontally or vertically aligned) The angle computation is easy as I wrote in his previous question (by use of 2 x `atan2 or atanxy` like `ang=|atan2(dir1)-atan2(dir2)|` or by single `acos(dot(dir1,dir2))`

Comment: @Spektre thanks for your advice, I have found the solution.but your suggestion about angle and Salai's answer can be combined to be comparation technique. Thanks

Comment: @ArseneWe If you found our answer's helpful, consider accepting our answers. Also if possible, as you said you can post your own answer by combining our answers and show us your results :)